# Как отправить данные GET запросом с помощью AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Хочу сделать GET запрос с данными из атрибутов, как это можно сделать с помощью AJAX?

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    xhr.open('GET', 'index.php', true);
    xhr.send(1);
};
```

```html
<div data-num='1'>1</div>
<div data-num='2'>2</div>
<div data-num='3'>3</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я хочу сделать GET запрос с данными из дата атрибутов, как это можно сделать с помощью AJAX?

Используйте [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

1. Пример с GET:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var fdata = '';

divs.forEach(function(v, i) {
  // Сборка JSON не самый оптимизированый вариант
  fdata += `data-num${i + 1}=${v.getAttribute('data-num')}`;
  if (i < divs.length - 1)
    fdata += '&';
})
console.log(fdata); // Debbug 
// Пример того что это работает
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1';
//var url = 'your-site.some/com?' + fdata; // Ваша ссылка будет тут
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });
```

```html
<div data-num='1'>1</div>
<div data-num='2'>2</div>
<div data-num='3'>3</div>
```

---

2. Пример с POST:

   ```js
   var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
   var fdata = [];

   divs.forEach(function(v, i) {
     // Create JSON
     fdata[i] = {
       'data-num': v.getAttribute('data-num')
     };
   })
   console.log(fdata); // Debbug 
   // 
   var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
   fetch(url, {
       method: 'post',
       body: JSON.stringify(fdata)
     })
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(function(data) { // Response is increasing number
       console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
     })
     .catch(function(error) {
       console.log('Request failed', error);
     });
   ```

   ```html
   <div data-num='1'>1</div>
   <div data-num='2'>2</div>
   <div data-num='3'>3</div>
   ```